# volcano plot color by variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a volcano plot of some metabolomics data with ggplot2. It is working well and I have it colored to reflect p-value and fold change cut offs. However I'd like the dots to be deferentially colored based on the value in the column 'variable'.

```
volcano = ggplot(foldpg, aes(x=log2fold, y=logp, colour=posthreshold)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5, size=2.5) +
 theme(legend.position = "none") +
xlim(c(-5, 5)) + ylim(c(0, 12)) +
xlab("log2 fold change") + ylab("-log10 p-value")
volcano
```

the "variable" column of `foldpg` has four possible values - I'd like a unique color for each.

Thanks

Comment: color = posthreshold already colored your points, I don't think it's possible to color points based on both 'posthreshold' and 'variable'.

Comment: you could use different shapes for  'variable' if you are coloring based on posthreshold.

Comment: Please provide some example data from `foldpg`.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  If posting the data in the question is too cumbersome, post it in a github gist.    You might be able to get the graphic your are looking for by using `colour = interaction(variable, posthreshold)` in the aesthetics.

Answer (score 1):

I generated a data frame `foldpg` with three variables

```
x=log2fold
y=logp
variable
```

the "variable" column of `foldpg` has four possible values `A, B, C, D`

```
log2fold<-runif(100, -1, 1)
logp<-runif(100, -5, 5)
variable<-sample( LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE)
foldpg<- data.frame(variable, log2fold, logp)
```

with `geom_point(aes(colour = variable))` you set the four colours while with `scale_colour_manual` you can assign the colours to the four values `A, B, C, D`.

```
volcano = ggplot(foldpg, aes(x=log2fold, y=logp)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = variable), alpha=0.5, size=2.5) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("A"= "yellow", "B"="red",  "C"= 
  "black", "D"="green"))
volcano
```

However you will need to exclude `colour=posthreshold`